# Questions from ru.SO shouldn't become hot

Tags: bug, status-completed, hot-questions, russian-stackoverflow

Apparently, the localized sites, such as pt.SO and ja.SO are exluded from the Hot Network Questions list. But recently launched ru.SO doesn't have its questions exluded from it:

> [image]

Plzfix?

Comment: In Stack Exchange Russia, hot networks question you!

Comment: This post isn't the place to have the "should we include localized sites in hot network questions" debate. 1. That boat has sailed, decision has been made. 2. If you want to change it, a [feature-request] or a [discussion] is the way to go. Make your case in a post, not in comments on a bug report.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Извиняюсь. Мы забыли изменить некоторые настройки после запуска сайта.

Comment: [translate.google.com](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%8C.%20%D0%9C%D1%8B%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0.) --> Sorry. Little bugs are hanged, but great ones escape.

Comment: Ich akzeptiere deine Entschuldigung. :)

Comment: Zie je, al die talen gaan best samen....

Comment: @nicael Obrigado. :)

Comment: And when are the changes supposed to go live? [This Q](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413068/Почему-нельзя-запустить-android-приложение-на-linux) still pops as hot quite often.

Comment: @nicael The list is cached for 24 hours.

Comment: J'accepte vos excuses. :)