# Hot Questions English Filter Broken

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, hot-questions, languages

The [Hot Questions English filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94526/138636) isn't working. I have seen all of the following in the Hot Questions list since yesterday:

[¿Qué quiere decir "comer la oreja" a alguien?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/12389)

[Почему нельзя запустить android приложение на Linux?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413068)

[Come si chiama quello che suona per segnare la fine di una lezione?](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5322)

Answer (score 6):

It's working.

Neither Italian nor Spanish sites are intentionally omitted - those sites are for *English speakers* who are learning those languages, so there's no expectation that these aren't of interest because the titles are guaranteed to be in a different language.

[Russian Stack Overflow was excluded yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252518/questions-from-ru-so-shouldnt-become-hot), the questions list will catch up as cache expires.

<sub>(Having said that, this is not so much an exclusion as it's a check for a certain amount of English in the title and body - I don't have the specifics in front of me - so it may make sense to flip this check on for language learner sites. But that's a feature-request. I don't know off-hand what the impact would be and whether the change is desirable. :))</sub>

Comment: I don't follow. The answer I referenced seems to be saying that posts will not be included on the hot list unless they contain a certain amount of English text. Neither the Spanish nor the Italian question contain a word of English.

Comment: @AndrewMedico The check isn't running on either of them right now. It's not enabled. That part is (at the moment) by design because we expect most titles on those sites to be in English anyway.