# Block Non-English Ukrainian Posts From HNQ

Tags: bug, hot-questions

At least five posts from http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com have made it to HNQ in the last 24 hours (728, 760, 762, 769, 776) - all in Ukrainian, not English. The site should be subject to the same "[English threshold](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94526/)" that applies to other sites with high quantities of non-English posts.

Comment: Just FYI: None of those sites have requirements to post in English. Their communities are just more prone to English questions than other language sites.

Comment: Previously @AdamLear said that [the Spanish, Italian, and Russian sites were excluded from the language filter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252640) because "those sites are for English speakers who are learning those languages". http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93535 also indicates that only English titles should end up in HNQ. That's not working here.

Comment: You're misinterpreting that as "questions must be in English" which is completely untrue. We actively *encourage* language communities to allow questions in that language, because immersive language learning is far more effective in most cases. The same answer there probably applies here too: the language filter is likely not enabled on Ukrainian. It probably should be, considering that the majority of the questions there are asked in that language, which isn't true on some other language sites.

Comment: All I know is - per SE Moderators - HNQ is supposed to contain only English-language posts for broad appeal. I don't care whether that's achieved by filtering or enforcing posting rules where they exist. Whichever one applies is fine.

Comment: @AdamLear says [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/257212/) that there should be "a checklist for all the different things we have to tweak when launching (or importing) a non-English site" so I assume that hasn't happened and this was just an oversight.