# Hot Network Questions should exclude the Spanish SO too

Tags: bug, hot-questions

In a similar vein to [Questions from ru.SO shouldn't become hot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252518/questions-from-ru-so-shouldnt-become-hot), questions from es.SO should probably be excluded from the Hot Network Questions list, at least until a [better way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256614/include-non-english-websites-in-hot-network-questions-based-on-users-location) of handling them can be implemented.

[image]

[image]

[image]