# Questions from SO in Russian is still on Hot Network Question list

Tags: bug, status-completed, hot-questions, russian-stackoverflow

According to this question: [Questions from ru.SO shouldn't become hot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252518/339911) entire ruSO site shouldn't become hot. But I just saw the following while searching MSE:

> [image: ruSO still hot]

Direct link to the question on ruSO: [local storage : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/949940/local-storage-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-innerhtml-of-null)

Perhaps the HNQ filter works on question title (in the current case there are no non-Latin symbols) instead of site origin. Hence, according to the post mentioned before this behaviour should be interpreted as a bug.

However, I suggest to fix such "bug" by taking another feature request in mind:
[Include non-English websites in Hot Network Questions, based on user's location/language/IP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256614/339911)

Comment: Likely related to [Are meta questions now featuring in Hot Network Questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324487/369403), which got fixed yesterday. The presence of ruSO HNQs has already been noted in the comments on the answer there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

International Stack Overflow sites are now excluded from the Hot Network Questions list entirely.

Comment: And you are sure that this also includes rus.SE (Russian language in Russian) as well?

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog I did say "Stack Overflow sites". :P I forgot about rus.SE when I flipped the settings earlier, but it's also excluded now.