# Questions from rus.SE shouldn't become hot

Tags: bug, status-completed, hot-questions

Localised sites such as [pt.SO, ja.SO and ru.SO have been hidden from the Hot Network Questions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252518/questions-from-ru-so-shouldnt-become-hot).

However, questions from [rus.SE](https://rus.stackexchange.com/) do appear, as has just occurred:

> [image]

<sup>[Link to question](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/415864/)</sup>

Can rus.SE also be excluded from the Hot Network Questions list?

Comment: @user4098326 That's a feature request about not including the sites. This isn't a duplicate because this is a bug report regarding the feature that has been implemented.

Comment: I think you're conflating features. Localised SO sites may be excluded, but language learning sites like [german.se], [japanese.se] aren't.

Comment: @muru Those sites have English words in their question title and body and the UI is in English. The UI of rus.SE is not in English.

Comment: @grgarside Was that question linked to `rus.stackexchange.com` or `russian.stackexchange.com`? They're both the same, AFAICT, but `rus.se` is localised.

Comment: @muru rus.stackexchange.com. The 'link to question' is the destination of the link from the hot network questions in the sidebar.

Comment: @muru Nope, different sites.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One of these days we'll make a checklist for all the different things we have to tweak when launching (or importing) a non-English site.

... but today is not that day.

Fixed, but it will take a bit for the hot questions cache to update and drop questions from rus.SE.

Comment: FWIW [¿Qué nombre recibe este sonido (o la acción de producirlo)?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/13231/qu%c3%a9-nombre-recibe-este-sonido-o-la-acci%c3%b3n-de-producirlo) is in the hot list now - нехорошо?

Comment: @gnat We don't exclude "language learning" sites on the assumption that most questions there will actually be in English, from people who are learning the language.

Comment: I see, thanks! makes sense

Comment: okay Anna, SO in Portuguese doesn't qualify as language learning site, correct? I ask because this question just leaked into Hot Network List and currently sits at #7 over there: [finalidade de continue? em c](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80589/finalidade-de-continue-em-c)