# Regression - questions from pt.SO are showing up in Hot Network Questions

Tags: bug, status-norepro, hot-questions, portuguese-stackoverflow

Spotted just now on Meta.SE:

[image: "Finalidade de continue em C?"]

This is probably not supposed to happen, per [Questions from rus.SE shouldn't become hot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257066/) and [Questions from ru.SO shouldn't become hot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252518/).