# HNQ has been hacked by the Russians

Tags: discussion, hot-questions, russian-stackoverflow, english

[image]

A question from the Russian language edition of Stack Overflow has appeared in the HNQ: [Ошибка Another git process seems to be running in this repository](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/674360/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-another-git-process-seems-to-be-running-in-this-repository). A significant amount of the title, and the body, are in English because it's quoting an error message.

Previous post from 2015, which indicates the Russian edition of Stack Overflow is blocked: [Questions from ru.SO shouldn't become hot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252518/questions-from-ru-so-shouldnt-become-hot)

Comment: Fake news!!!!!!

Comment: Related: [Should “Hot Network Questions” show questions from non-English-language sites if you're on an English-language site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350137/616460)

Comment: Seeing how well this solves the problem of vote inflation - the top answer has a score of 7, as opposed to going into the hundreds, maybe we should make sure that all HNQ questions get translated to foreign languages (on their original site, no less, so the people clicking through don't dare vote after trying to read them).

Comment: Happened again today: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/949940/local-storage-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-innerhtml-of-null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way this works is, these sites have an additional check run on their titles before they're allowed on the hot network questions list - if they don't look like they're mostly English, they get culled.

This one happens to look mostly English.

Comment: What's the rationale behind that? Surely, even if the title is mostly English, everything else on the site is still in another language... I mean, I can't even figure out how to create an account to post an answer even if I could understand the question

Comment: If memory serves, this logic was originally created for sites like [german.se], where questions are regularly asked in both languages; thus, it serves to exclude only those which are not English.

Comment: Yeh that makes sense, not so much on the SO language variants though IMO

Comment: Agree; clearly the proper solution here is to construct a Russian-translated version of git so that error messages appear non-English to the HNQ logic.

Comment: Sure, or ya know, just exclude the foreign language sites completely and keep the checks to the sites *about* foreign languages :)

Comment: @Cai surely it is simpler for us to ignore HNQs in a language we don't speak? I see no reason to limit the HNQs to English in the first place. If you don't speak the language, you won't find it interesting and you can just ignore it. But those who do speak the language can get the dubious pleasure of HNQs which is denied them if they are all in English.

Comment: I see [this question](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/8567/2505), fully written in Italian from [italian.se] is now in the HNQ.

Comment: Should be fixed now @fedorqui

Comment: How you explain [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxCoT.png)? Not a single English word in the title. ([question source](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/41888/sich-in-etwas-reinh%C3%A4ngen))

Comment: Believe it or not, "sich", "in" and "etwas" all appear in the English word list that we use for this purpose, @Shadow

Comment: Huh. Thanks for teaching me two new words in English! ;)