# Japanese SO question appears in HNQ

Tags: bug, hot-questions, languages

Well, it looks like it's that time of the year again!

[image: Screenshot of HNQ]

[This post](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/53077/kill-0-pid-%e3%81%af%e4%bd%95%e3%82%92%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%81%ae%e3%81%a7%e3%81%97%e3%82%87%e3%81%86%e3%81%8b) appears in HNQ. It probably shouldn't, for reasons discussed previously.

Related: [HNQ has been hacked by the Russians](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296686/hnq-has-been-hacked-by-the-russians), [Should "Hot Network Questions" show questions from non-English-language sites if you're on an English-language site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350137/should-hot-network-questions-show-questions-from-non-english-language-sites-if)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Questions from SO in Russian is still on Hot Network Question list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324576/questions-from-so-in-russian-is-still-on-hot-network-question-list) - Other site, same bug

Comment: @MEEthesetupwizard Almost certainly related (and didn't come up when I searched?) but from what I can tell the issue there was it only checked the title, not the body -- and the ru question had an en title. In this case the majority of the title is ja. I'll poke a comment on there, thanks.

Comment: You’ll see that the possible duplicate links to a completed bug report that explains why such bugs occur.

Comment: @MEEthesetupwizard Yes, I already clicked through.Yes, it explains the change SO is making that could've caused issues. [Specifically, that they're now checking titles only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324487/are-meta-questions-now-featuring-in-hot-network-questions#comment1060317_324489). But here is a case where the title is mostly non-English, unlike the Russian example with English title. VtC if you want, but I'm not going to self-delete because I want SO to be aware of this case.

Comment: @Bob, no, there is per-site setting that cause them to be excluded from the list, when checked, e.g. it's mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252518/questions-from-ru-so-shouldnt-become-hot?noredirect=1&lq=1). The bug is that it's no longer checking that setting. (Same way it didn't check for meta, which is fixed.)

Comment: I find I cannot understand half the HNQ titles anyway even when they are apparently in English so the odd bit of Japanese/Russian does not bother me. But I do seem to be in a minority.

Comment: Technically "kill" and "PID" would be detected as English and so the title barely falls under the 75% cutoff, so I think it's the same issue.